# Data validation for registration page in stored procedure which should give error message in asp.net page when the data field is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

This is my stored procedure for the registration page:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE reguser
    @firstname varchar(20),
    @lastname varchar(20),
    @username VARCHAR(20),
    @password varchar(20),
    @dob varchar(20),
    @Phonenumber varchar(10) = null
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    INSERT INTO users(firstname, lastname, username, password, dob, Phonenumber) 
    VALUES (@firstname, @lastname, @username, @password, @dob, @Phonenumber)
END
```

This is `registration.asp.cs`

```
protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
       submit.Text = "Registered";
    }

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "reguser";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", firstname.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", lastname.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", email.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", dob.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phonenumber", phone.Text);

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);

    if (dt.Rows.Count > 1)
    {
        Label1.Text = "Registration Sucessfull!!!";
    }

    //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.Connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: It is poor approach of validating the input data by hitting the db, try to do this in client side first, then within server side, after validating your data, make a call to the db. Remember to only call db when you want to store/retrieve/update data. Avoid otherwise.

Comment: I have created validation in asp using required field validation but as per my requirement i need validation from stored procedure

Comment: `raiserror` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql

Comment: Please elaborate your problem. Where are you stuck?

Comment: I have created a registration page with required field validation in asp which shows error messages for each text box , but now i need the validation to be implemented in stored procedure with the insert values

Answer (score 0):

Use if statement like this:

```
if(firstname.Text.Trim().Lenght>0 && lastname.Text.Trim().Lenght >0 && email.Text.Trim().Lenght>0 && password.Text.Trim().Lenght>0 && dob.Text.Trim().Lenght>0 && phone.Text.Text.Trim().Lenght>0)
{
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "reguser";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", firstname.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", lastname.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", email.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", dob.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phonenumber", phone.Text);

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);

    if (dt.Rows.Count > 1)
    {
        Label1.Text = "Registration Sucessfull!!!";
    }

    //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.Connection.Close();
}
else
{
     //Required fields fill up
}
```